# Get Property Name

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get the property name of the value that was passed into a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you asking if this is possible?

```
public void PrintPropertyName(int value) {
    Console.WriteLine(someMagicCodeThatPrintsThePropertyName);
}

// x is SomeClass having a property named SomeNumber
PrintInteger(x => x.SomeNumber);
```

and "SomeNumber" will be printed to the console?

If so, no. That is clearly impossible (hint: What happens on `PrintPropertyName(5)`?). But you can do this:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expression) {
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(expression != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(expression);
    return propertyInfo.Name;
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expression) {
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(expression != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<PropertyInfo>() != null);
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    Guard.Against<ArgumentException>(memberExpression == null, "Expression does not represent a member expression.");
    var propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
    Guard.Against<ArgumentException>(propertyInfo == null, "Expression does not represent a property expression.");
    Type type = typeof(TSource);
    Guard.Against<ArgumentException>(type != propertyInfo.ReflectedType && type.IsSubclassOf(propertyInfo.ReflectedType));
    return propertyInfo;
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = GetPropertyName((SomeClass x) => x.SomeNumber);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

and now "SomeNumber" will be printed to the console.

Answer (score 5):

Only if you use a lambda, I.e.

```
SomeMethod(()=>someObj.PropName);
```

(an having the method take a typed expression tree instead of just a value)

However this still takes quite a bit of processing to resolve and involves both reflection and Expression. I would avoid this unless absolutely necessary. It isn't worth learning Expression just for this.

Comment: @Adeel Don't be so quick to edit.  Give the guy a chance to edit his own stuff!  I think it is respectful to wait five minutes.

Comment: @Josh - I don't mind; I'm on iPod so I wouldn't have noticed unless he edited

Comment: @Josh yes i will take care of it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

No. The property will be evaluated *before* the function is called, and the actual value in the function will be a *copy* of that value, not the property itself.