# Obtaining name of property without passing it in via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    public static class Validate
    {
        public static void AgainstNull(string str)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            {
                // how do I know the property name in the calling code?
                throw new ArgumentNullException("property name from caller");
            }
        }
    }
```

So that I can use a pattern similar to this in my code base:

```
    public void Foo(string bar)
    {
        Validate.AgainstNull(bar);

        // other processing here
    }
```

How do I know the name of the property which was passed in from the calling code inside of my validate method?

Comment: Theoretically you _could_ use LINQ expressions ala `Validate.AgainstNull(() => bar)`, but I'm not sure if the performance hit of essentially compiling, invoking, and inspecting those expressions makes it worthwhile. I've done it in the past where simply I've passed in both the object I'm checking and its name as a string. Have you considered using [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4099275/945456

Comment: Wrong question.  How do you know the name of the property that got passed to Foo()?  And then, how do you know the name of the property that got passed to Bar() that called Foo()?  Baz is next, ad infinitum.  This of course cannot work, which is why NRE works the way it does.

Comment: In your example do you want to return `Foo` (which is not a "property" or the property that _calls_ `Foo`?

Answer (score 3):

As Chris Sinclair mentioned, you can use LINQ expression, here is an example of such code:

```
public static class Validate
{
    public static void AgainstNull(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<string>> expr)
    {
        var str = expr.Compile().Invoke();
        if (str == null)
        {
            string name = (expr.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member.Name;
            throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you call it?

Comment: @JeffBridgman: `Validate.AgainstNull(() => bar);` (though in this case, the method might be updated to use a generic `T` instead of `string`)

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly possible, but there's a technique/hack that allows the retrieval of the parameter names by making them members of an anonymous type.

Based on your example, this is *not* a fit. It introduces unnecessary ambiguity and requires weakly typed method signature(s). It's also measurably slower than just passing the string name of the parameter in question.

Again, don't use this for the stated purpose.

**Code**

```
void Main()
{
    Foo( "hello", "world", 123, false );
}

private static void Foo( string bar, string baz, int abc, bool xyz )
{
    Evaluate( new { bar, baz, abc, xyz } );
}

private static void Evaluate( object o )
{
    var properties = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties( o );
    foreach( System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor in properties )
    {
        var value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue( o );
        Console.WriteLine( "Name: {0}, Value: {1}", propertyDescriptor.Name, value );
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Name: bar, Value: hello
Name: baz, Value: world
Name: abc, Value: 123
Name: xyz, Value: False
```

**When might this pattern be appropriate?**

It's worth noting that the ASP.Net MVC framework uses anonymous types extensively as a syntactic shortcut. The `ComponentModel` code comes straight from `RouteValueDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't.

There are [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh534540.aspx) in newer version of .NET that I thought would be helpful, but those don't look like they'd do the trick either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expression Tree to get names of parameters

```
    public static class Validate
    {
        public static void AgainstNull(string str)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            {
                var parametersNames = GetParameterNames(() => AgainstNull(str));
                throw new ArgumentNullException(parametersNames[0]);
            }
        }

        private static string[] GetParameterNames(Expression<Action> expression)
        {
            var methodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method;
            var names = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name);
            return names.ToArray();
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void AgainstNullTest()
    {
        var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => Validate.AgainstNull(string.Empty));

        Assert.True(ex.Message.EndsWith("str"));
    }
```